# What is the best way to get a user's information from another table from a user_id column in one table?

Tags: sql

I am attempting to create a blog stream which will load posts in blocks of ten. Currently, my schema for a post contains a column named "AUTHOR_ID" which references the user ID of the author who created the post. This is so if the author's name changes, it will be updated when the stream is loaded.

My question is what is the most efficient way to load the author's name from another user table based off of the AUTHOR_ID from the post table?

My first idea was to use a UNION, but I can't seem to find a way to do this considering they don't have the same number of columns. The second option was to just run a query for each post loaded, but I feel this is inefficient.

What are your ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't share the database.  I suspect this is a duplicate but I don't find it.  You are describing a foreign key.

```
Author table 
ID int primary key 
Name varchar(100)

Post table 
authorID int FK to Author.ID 
post varchar(max)  

select a.name, p.post 
from author a  
join post p 
     on p.authorID = a.ID
```